# $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions which satisfy $f(g(x)) = x^2$ and $g(f(x)) = x^3$ for all $x \ge 1$. If $g(16) = 16$, then compute $\log_2 g(4)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions which satisfy $f(g(x))=x^2$ and $g(f(x))=x^3$ for all $x\ge 1$. If $g(16)=16$, then compute $\log_2g(4)$.

(You may assume that $f(x) \ge 1$ and $g(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \ge 1$.) I'm kind of stuck. Can someone please show me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Question should be self contained, and not a continuation of the title.

Comment: Please accept the answer, or write an answer of your own and close the question.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $16 = 4^2$,we have that $g(16)  = g(f(g(4))) = 16$. This implies that $g(4)^3 = 16$, so that $3\log_2 g(4) = 4$, which gives $\log_2 g(4) = \frac 43$.

Comment: Having said this, can you actually find two functions which satisfy this property? I could not.

Comment: It can be deduced that g(x^2)=g(x)^3 by plugging g(x) into the second equation for x. I put this property along with g(16)=16 into wolfram alpha's recurrence relation solver, and it says there is no solution.

Comment: That is what I had  expected in the first place. Thank you for informing me.